# Angular 4. Relogin with different user account not showing current user until you reload page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm storing user session in local storage. I clear each time page is logged out. But when I log in with a different user, the old user account is shown unless I reload the page.

I'm using the routing method below to go to the dashboard to log in.

`this._router.navigate(['/pages/dashboard']);`

Comment: You need to show more implementation.

Comment: Please provide us minimum reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign new user details to localstorage.
i am also done right now.
its work fine.

Comment: Thanks. When i get to the dashboard i can see previous logged in user. But when i reload the same dashboard page. It loads new current user.